# Change css attributes of previous class

Tags: jquery

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="hold_image">
    <div class="SiteName">guitars.com</div>
    <a href="/image/Guitars/1236">
        <img src="//mysite.com/images/production/1236.jpg" class="Image">
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to change the parent outer div (class="hold_image") to have a different color background when the image loads and am trying:

```
$(".Image").on('load', function () {
    $(this).prev('.hold_image').css('background-color','#ffffff');
});
```

But nothing changes. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try $('.hold_image').css('background-color','#ffffff');

Comment: My question is when the class name is fixed to .hold_image, why to search by using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi instead of `prev` you want to use `closest('.hold_image')`. This selector searches up the dom tree until it has a match.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.prev()`, you want to use `.parents().eq(1)`.